# When should I be considering using threading

Tags: python, multithreading, model-view-controller, python-multithreading

I am creating an application in Python that uses SQLite databases and wxPython. I want to implement it using MVC in some way. I am just curious about threading. Should I be doing this in any scenario that uses a GUI? Would this kind of application require it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

almost certainly you already are...

alot of wx is already driven by an asynchronous event loop ..

that said you should use wx.PubSub for communication within an MVC style wx Application, but it is unlikely that you will need to implement any kind of threading (you get it for free practically)

a few good places to python threading(locked by gil) use are:

- serial communication
- socket servers

a few places to use multiprocessing (still locked by gil but at least it sends it to different cores)

- bitcoin miners
- anything that requires massive amounts of data processing that can be parallelized

there are lots more places to use it, however most gui are already fairly asynchronously driven by events (not entirely true, but close enough), and sqlite3 queries definitely should be executed one at a time from the same thread(in fact sqlite breaks horribly if you try to write to it in two different threads)

this is likely all a gross oversimplification

Comment: it has lots of value ... if you need to implement asynchronous stuff ... a gui however already runs asynchronously. I will add some examples of good places to use threading

Comment: In the stuff I have read, it says that threading with a GUI can be useful as it can make the GUI appear more responsive?

Comment: if you have stuff that takes a long time sure .... you would not want to block the gui ... but what your talking about is fairly responsive

Comment: Ok. So it shouldn't be necessary. Ultimately this application will also run across a network. Would it be required then or still not?

Comment: premature optimization is the root of all evil ... what do you mean when you say it will run across a network?  wPython typically runs on a desktop ... sqlite3 does not like concurrent connections at all I think I am lacking information about your project to help you decide if you will want to use it... but in general I dont think you will need to

Comment: Sorry. To clarify, I know SQLite doesn't like to work across a network but I don't really have a choice. I need an embedded db and it needs to be accessed by several computers on a network. I'm looking to a bigger scope later on where the DB will be hosted on the server and it will use PostgreSQL/MySQL. That should be fairly simple to change if the MVC is implemented correctly.

Comment: Then it really shouldn't be an issue. This application is basically a GUI interfacing with a fairly complex DB. very little other than that going on in reality. Thanks for all the help. I'll accept your answer because it came first and you have made the most comments :P

Answer (score 1):

One thing I learned from javascript/node.js is that there is a difference between asynchronous programming and parallel programming.  In asynchronous programming you may have things running out of sequence, but any given task runs to completion before something else starts running.  That way you don't have to worry about synchronizing shared resources with semaphores and locks and things like that, which would be an issue if you have multiple threads running in parallel, with either run simultaneously or might get preempted, thus the need for locks.

Most likely you are doing some sort of asynchronous code in a gui environment, and there isn't any need for you to also do parallel multi-threaded code.

Comment: thats basically what I was trying to say in my answer but yeah +1 all the same :P

Answer (score 1):

You will use multithreading to perform parallel or background tasks that you don't want the main thread to wait, you don't want it to hang the GUI while it runs, or interfer with the user interactivity, or some other priority tasks.

Most applications today don't use multithreading or use very little of it. Even if they do use multi threads, its usually because of libraries the final programmer is using and isn't even aware that multithreading is happening there as he developed his application.

Even major softwares like AutoCAD use very little multithreading. It's not that its poorly made, but multithreading has very specific applications. For instance, it is pointless to allow user interaction while the project he wants to work on is still loading. A software designed to interact with a single user will hardly need it.

Where you can see multithreading fit a really important role is in servers, where a single application can attend requests from thousands of users without interfering with each other. In this scenario the easier way to make sure everyone is happy is by creating a new thread to each request.

Comment: That makes good sense. So I'll leave it out for now and if the scope of the project changes then re-evaluate if there is a requirement.

Comment: bah everyone basically agrees with me ... and I get the downvote (any way +1 to both you guys ... solid answers)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, GUIs are typically single threaded implementations where a single thread (called UI thread) keeps polling for events and keeps executing them in the order they occur.

Regarding the main question, consider this scenario.

At the click of a button you want to do something time consuming that takes say 5-10 seconds or more. You have got 2 options.

1. Do that operation in the main UI thread itself. This will freeze the UI for that duration and user will not be able to interact with it.
2. Do that operation in a separate thread that would on completion just notify the main UI thread (in case UI thread needs to make any UI updates based on result of the operation). This option will not block the UI thread and user can continue to use the application.

However, there will be situations where you do not want user to be using the application while something happens. In such cases usually you can still use a separate thread but block the UI using some sort of overlay / progress indicator combination.

Comment: Since I am not reputed enough on SOF to comment on other's answers, I wanted to add a note around Javascript and UIs done in other languages. Javascript was designed to be single threaded language (pre web worker days) so there was not much scope of doing parallel programming. Depending on the kind of UI application you are doing, parallel programming may make sense. For ex: Java swing applications do have very genuine cases.

Comment: That's exactly the way I understood it. So is the solution to code the thing and see if such a scenario occurs. At the point when it does, include multithreading (if scenario 2). Otherwise don't overcomplicate?

Comment: Absolutely, introduce multithreading only if needed. But be careful on how you judge "if needed". For ex: if you are doing any disk reads or network reads, depending on size of data the time taken may vary and hence it is always better to not do such things in UI thread unless there are asynchronous APIs provided by the platform.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will then continue as I was and investigate this again if/when needed.

Comment: Cool. Good luck with your application.